# Backreference in PHP

Tags: 7, entities

I have a Content Type **Courses**  & a User Role **Student**

In the student I used EntityReference to refer to a number of courses.

Is it possible to get a list of all the students that have a particular course referenced to them, in PHP?

Right now I'm only accustomed in getting a value from a field in a content type like this:

```
$user_surname = $profile_info['student']->field_surname['und'][0]['value'];
```

---

**PS** I think this has to do with back-reference,which is a module I already installed.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: You really should not be manually accessing field_surname, you should be using [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7/search/field_get_items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with views (without PHP), but if you want to use PHP you should check out [Entity Field Query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)

You will have to do something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('your_field_course', 'target_id', $nid, '=')
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.
$result = $query->execute();
if (isset($result['user'])) {
  $uids = array_keys($result['user']);
  $users = entity_load('user', $uids);
}
```